# There is uniqueness of solution to the problem $-\Delta u + u^4 =0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplacian, elliptic-equations

help me in the following situation: If we take the equation
$$-\Delta u + u^4 = 0 \ \ \mbox{in} \ \ \mathbb{R}^2,$$
with $u \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, then it is easy to see that $u \equiv 0$ is a trivial solution to the problem. Hence, the following question arises: is it possible to find another non-constant $u$ function that satisfies the previous problem?

This caused me doubt because it is well known that if we assign boundary conditions, then we can guarantee the uniqueness of problems similar to the one I proposed.

Comment: No I doubt that you will have uniqueness. For example, you could assume radial symmetry in $u$ which will give you a second order ODE. You probably won’t be able to solve this but standard ODE theory will likely give you some existence and uniqueness given initial conditions. By changing the ICs you will ‘find’ many solutions

Comment: With his ideas, I was able to justify that, in the case of radially symmetric functions, there will be singularities in the solutions sought. But for the general case? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, we will most certainly be able to find other solutions, but they may or may not be unique. We need boundary conditions to talk about uniqueness.